# Websocket with python Bottle + uwsgi | env vars

Tags: python, websocket, uwsgi, bottle

I actually try to set up a bottle python application based on uwsgi. I need uwsgi for websocket support.

My really basic code looks like that:
(webserver.py)

```
from bottle import route, run, static_file, error, template
import uwsgi
import bottle
from bottle import route, template

    app = application = bottle.default_app() 

    @route('/')
    def index():
          uwsgi.websocket_handshake(env['HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY'], env('HTTP_ORIGIN', ''))
          while True:
              msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv()
              uwsgi.websocket_send(msg)
          return template('inputs', name='inputs')

    @route('/static/<filepath:path>')
    def server_static(filepath):
        return static_file(filepath, root='./static/')
```

I just start this file by:

```
uwsgi --http-socket :80 --http-websockets --wsgi-file webserver.py
```

My error message looks like that:

```
...
uwsgi.websocket_handshake(env['HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY'], env('HTTP_ORIGIN', ''))
NameError: global name 'env' is not defined
...
```

The websocket handshakes needs the env vars but I got no idea what it is and how to implement them to my code.

EDIT: I already tried to import env by

```
from uwsgi import env
```

but it doesn't solve the proble.

Comment: You have no import of env, it's not a built-in function; where did you think it was coming from?

Comment: Well if I import the uwsgi env by "from envparse import env" I get the following error message:  no python application found, check your startup logs for errors.